# Cannot locate a partial id on selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Hi everyone !

I am trying to locate an element with a dynamic ID, but ! whatever i do, the except NoSuchElementException is systematically raised...

There is my code :

```
try:
    driver.get('http://www.website.com/')
    usr = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a[id*='txtEmail']")
    pwd = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a[id*='txtPassword']")

    usr.send_keys(username)
    pwd.send_keys(password)
    driver.find_element_by_css_Selector("a[id*='btnLogin']").click()

    if (driver.find_element_by_css_Selector("a[id$=lnkLogOut]")):
            log.info("Successfully connected")
    else:
            log.error("Login failed - Cannot login to the website - Wrong username/password ?")

    except NoSuchElementException:
            log.error("Cannot find element needed on the login page")

    except TimeoutException:
            log.error("Cannot reach the website in time")
    except:
            log.error("Error occurred during the login attempt: {}".format(sys.exc_info()))
```

There is the html form:

```
<td>Email/Username:</td>
<td><input name="ctl00$cph1$Login1$txtEmail" id="ctl00_cph1_Login1_txtEmail" style="width:160px;" type="text"></td>

<td>Password:</td>
<td><input name="ctl00$cph1$Login1$txtPassword" id="ctl00_cph1_Login1_txtPassword" style="width:160px;" type="password"></td>
<td><input name="ctl00$cph1$Login1$btnLogin" value="Login" id="ctl00_cph1_Login1_btnLogin" class="fancy" with="80px;" style="height:28px;" type="submit"></td>
```

And there is my output error:

```
DEBUG:selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection:POST 

http://127.0.0.1:40943/hub/session {"desiredCapabilities": {"platform": "ANY", "browserName": "firefox", "version": "", "marionette": false, "javascriptEnabled": true}}
DEBUG:selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection:Finished Request
DEBUG:selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection:POST http://127.0.0.1:40943/hub/session/2b64c16e-1582-42ee-8041-66550781c00f/url {"url": "http://www.website.com", "sessionId": "2b64c16e-1582-42ee-8041-66550781c00f"}
DEBUG:selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection:Finished Request
DEBUG:selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection:POST http://127.0.0.1:40943/hub/session/2b64c16e-1582-42ee-8041-66550781c00f/element {"using": "css selector", "sessionId": "2b64c16e-1582-42ee-8041-66550781c00f", "value": "a[id*='txtEmail']"}
DEBUG:selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection:Finished Request
ERROR:__main__:Cannot find element needed on the login page
```

Where's the problem ? Any idea ?

EDIT : The following lines provoke the error:

```
usr = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a[id*='txtEmail']")
pwd = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a[id*='txtPassword']")
```

Comment: Toshiro, without claiming to be a Python expert (I think I have only written Python code in a stackoverflow answer), I would recommend that you would comment out all code in your try except the first row and test. If you do not get the exception, then uncomment the second line and test. At the end of the search you will find the line causing the error. When you know which line has thrown the error, please, edit your question to have a better chance of getting an answer.

Comment: Didn't you try to add waitForElement? Didn't you try to access it not by id?

Comment: Expose full `xpath` to element please

Comment: You are trying to use the a css selector but if the element is dynamic you should use a xpath selector (find_by_xpath)

Comment: Ok, i tried the following line instead :

usr = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[contains(@id, "txtEmail")]')

And it worked !
However, i could not understand why with a css selector, this could not work, as i already set parameter with an " * " which means "contains" (cf. "a[id*='txtEmail']" )

Comment: Toshiro, which line was the responsible of the error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To follow the @murali's point about the `a` versus `input`, you can just fix your CSS selectors:

```
usr = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[id*=txtEmail]")
pwd = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[id*=txtPassword]")
```

You can also use the "ends-with" check instead of "contains":

```
usr = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[id$=txtEmail]")
pwd = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[id$=txtPassword]")
```

Comment: Thank you for this summarize :)

Answer (score 2):

As per provided HTML code tags for all means username, password and submit buttons are 'input' but in code used 'a' . so that is the reason for the issue.

As per comment following one worked

```
  usr = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[contains(@id, "txtEmail")]')
```

because here tag 'a' is not used in xpath instead '*' is used meany any tag so input here.

I am expecting logout button also have tag 'input' as HTML code for logout element is not provided. so please check that and create correct css or xpath so that time out exception will be resolved.

Thank You,
Murali

Comment: Ok i understand better why now. Thank you for the explanation provided !